# Relating Wordpress Users with Order Export

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, wpallimport

We are using Advanced Custom Fields, WP All Export Pro, and WordPress with Woocommerce.

I have an ACF field created for our accountant in users area of WordPress called "traverse_customer_id". This is for her to know what customer this order is for.

I have this ACF field showing in the orders export but the data comes back blank on each export. I think it's because I'm not relating the order with the customer or user ID.  I've attempted to use a code snippet from WP All Exports' support without any luck. Could anyone with knowledge help me see what I'm doing wrong?

This is what I have in the "Custom export field" area: (I think this is running the function on each line of the import.)

```
[sf_helper_meta_query_lookup("traverse_customer_id",{Customer User ID},"user")]
```

Then I have this below in the Function Editor:

```
function sf_helper_meta_query_lookup( $meta_key = '', $meta_value = '', $object_type = 'post', $taxonomy = '', $return_field = 'ID', $compare = '=', $custom_args = array() ) {
if ( empty( $object_type ) || empty( $meta_key ) || empty( $meta_value ) ) return;
$func = 'get_posts';

switch ( $object_type ) {
    case 'user':
        $func = 'get_users';
        break;
    case 'term':
        $func = 'get_terms';
        if ( $return_field == 'ID' ) {
            $return_field = 'term_id';
        }
        break;
    default:
        $func = 'get_posts';
        break;
}

if ( ! empty( $custom_args ) ) {
    $objects = $func( $custom_args );
    if ( ! empty( $objects ) ) {
        return $objects[0]->$return_field;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$args = array();

$meta_query = array( array(
    'key'     => $meta_key,
    'value'   => $meta_value,
    'compare' => $compare
) );

if ( $func == 'get_terms' ) {
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );
} elseif ( $func == 'get_users' ) {
    $args = array( 
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );
} else {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => $object_type,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );
}
        
if ( $objects = $func( $args ) ) {
    return $objects[0]->$return_field;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what type of field is the acf? relationship?

Comment: It's a simple text field. It's set to show on the user form.

Comment: Trying this too: function the_traverse_id($user_id,$customer_id,$travers_customer_id){

if($user_id == $customer_id){
return $travers_customer_id;

} else {return "";}}


Doc from our export software on custom functions: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/custom-wordpress-export-php/

Doc on how the user and customer data works in Wordpress and Woocommerce: https://usersinsights.com/woocommerce-customer-database/